# Using browser.wait() to do retry same actions/jobs repeatedly and synchronously

Tags: protractor

I have faced lots of difficulties in doing things synchronously or retrying same action again and again in protractor. I have got a way which seems not the best way but nonetheless works.
 The trick is to exploit `browser.wait()`.

I have implemented above for one of scenarios where counter was not getting immediately updated after doing a certain action and wanted to compare counter value before and after the action.To get the correct updated value it was required to refresh browser multiple times before the counter is updated in UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function retries 5 times to check whether counter got updated or not before bailing out.

```
//  icount : initial counter value(already fetched)
//  fcount : final counter value
//  foo : function used to fetch counter value
//  val : Maximum # of retries

 this.retryVerification = function(icount,foo,val){
            var retry = 0;
            browser.wait(function(){
                browser.refresh();
                browser.sleep(1000);
                var fcount = foo();
                return fcount.then(function(fcount){
                    fcount = parseInt(fcount);
                    retry = retry + 1;
                    return (fcount == (icount+1) || retry == val);
                });
            });
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `waitForAngular` like this:

```
browser.waitForAngular();
```

You can refer to this API:
[Protractor API for waitForAngular](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=Protractor.prototype.waitForAngular)

Comment: Yes, I do have used. But it just waits for angular page to load.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is angular/non-angular agnostic i.e. it can be applied anywhere and I am not using specifically for page to reload. I want the backend system to update the UI and hence I retrying multiple times.   Hopefully,it makes sense.